# Native mobile app vs cross compile framework

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform

I need to develop an app for both iOS and Android. As I conducted some research on the various technologies I may use, the results boiled down into two. I could either opt for developing both apps natively on their respective platforms or else use a cross compilation framework.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each? Do they both offer good solutions? I read that the cross compilation frameworks don't support all the native libraries, is this true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865277/mobile-development-native-vs-cross-platform-vs-javascript